# Passing command line arguments to a system script in Ansible role?

Tags: server, ansible

In ansible, how should I go about passing command line arguments to a system script?

For example, on the remote host

```
$ /usr/share/my-script \
--my-arg1=gist.github.com \
--my-arg2="foo bar"
```

The value `foo bar` is something which I need to define at the `role` level and something which changes with each system script.

If there would be a way to put the value of `foo bar` in `defaults` and then let `jinja2` replace it while the role runs. Any suggestions on how should I approach it?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov added my answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `script` module for achieving it, for example:

`- script: /usr/share/my-script --my-arg1 "{{ var1 }}" --my-arg2 "{{ var2 }}"`

As above you can define `var1` and `var2` default value in role vars files as below:

`var1: "gist.github.com"
var2: "foo bar"`

Also you can pass values at runtime as below:

`ansible-playbook -extra-vars "var1=gist1.github.com var2=abcxyz" <playbook_name>`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by

```
- name: foo bar
  shell: |
    /usr/share/my-script \
    --my-arg1=gist.github.com \
    --my-arg2={{ your_var }}
```

inside the role where I wanted to run my command.

You can define `your_var` at [different places](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) as allowed by ansible